# Play ScalaJSON Reads[T] parsing type mismatch error

Tags: json, scala, implicit-conversion

I have a big chunk of Json, of which I only care about a small subset e.g:

```
{
  "request": {
    "c": {
      "code": "AA",
      "fsCode": "AA"
    },
    "codeType": {},
    "number": {
      "requested": "100",
     },
  "scheduled": [
    {
      "code": "BB",
      "number": "100",
      "classes": [
        "F",
        "Y"
      ]
   }]
}
```

I just want to extract the `code` and `number` variables. I have tried using `Reads` as follows:

```
case class TheResult(result: (String, String))

implicit val theScheduledReads: Reads[TheResult] = (
    (__ \ "code").read[String] and
      (__ \ "number").read[String] tupled) map TheScheduledFlight.apply _

case class ResultList(addr: List[TheResult])

implicit val resultReads: Reads[ResultList] =
  (__ \ "scheduled").read(List[TheResult](theScheduledReads)) map ResultList _
```

and then this to access the result:

`response.json.validate[List[ResultList]]`

However, it throws this error:

`type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.json.Reads[details.client.TheResult]
 required: details.client. TheResult
    (__ \ "address").read(List[TheResult](resultReads)) map (TheResult.apply _)`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed multiple problems in the code. Have a look

Most importantly `read(List[TheResult](theScheduledReads))` makes no sense.
It should be `read[List[TheResult]]`

Replace `TheScheduledFlight.apply` with `TheResult.apply _`

```
case class TheResult(result: (String, String))

implicit val theScheduledReads: Reads[TheResult] = (
  (__ \ "code").read[String] and
    (__ \ "number").read[String] tupled) map TheResult.apply _ //problem fixed here

case class ResultList(addr: List[TheResult])

implicit val resultReads: Reads[ResultList] =
  (__ \ "scheduled").read[List[TheResult]] map ResultList.apply _ //problem fixed here
```